# QtConcurrent::run emit signal

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I would like to emit a signal in Qt, from a function that I called with QtConcurrent::run

Is this possible? It seems like my slot never gets called. All of the signals, slots, and functions are part of the same class object. I have tried making the connection in the Master thread, and in the slave thread. I dont really care if the signal and slot are in the same thread or not, I just want to get it to happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The below works just fine in Qt 4.8.7. The signal is emitted from the worker thread, and consumed in the main thread. We assert that the slot runs in the main thread, and the functor runs in the worker thread.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/concurrent-emit-qt4-7114421
#include <QtCore>

class Helper : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   int n = 0;
   Q_SLOT void increment() {
      Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() == qApp->thread());
      n++;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
   Helper helper;
   Q_ASSERT(helper.n == 0);
   QtConcurrent::run([&]{
      Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() != qApp->thread());
      QObject src;
      QObject::connect(&src, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), &helper, SLOT(increment()));
      QObject::connect(&src, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), &app, SLOT(quit()));
   });
   app.exec();
   Q_ASSERT(helper.n == 1);
}

#include "main.moc"
```

In Qt 5, you don't need the helper class to demonstrate that it works:

```
#include <QtConcurrent>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
   int n = 0;
   Q_ASSERT(n == 0);
   QtConcurrent::run([&]{
      Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() != qApp->thread());
      QObject src;
      QObject::connect(&src, &QObject::destroyed, &app, [&]{
         Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() == qApp->thread());
         n ++;
         qApp->quit();
      });
   });
   app.exec();
   Q_ASSERT(n == 1);
}
```

Comment: Qt got odd semantics for QFuture allowing it to be destroyed while  co-procedure is still running, which leads to odd behaviour . Note that its ISO analog's destructor waits. Strictly should  create QFuture object, call app.exec, then wait for QFuture to finish if it didn't yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Qt::QueuedConnection` for that connection (pass it to the `connect` call which establishes the connection), since the signal will always be emitted from a different thread than the receiver objects thread.

An `Qt::AutoConnection` will also do the same thing and add the signal to the event queue of the thread of the receiving object.

If the receiving thread is blocked, and thus never reenters the event queue, the signal cannot be received by the slot of the receiving object.

Comment: This is incorrect: the default automatic connection will do the job just fine.

Comment: @KubaOber: You are wrong. The OP said that all slots and signals belong to ONE object. Thus an AutoConnection will evaluate to a DirectConnection. This is probably not what OP wants, since that requires that the slots use the object in a thread-safe manner. This synchronization has to be done manually in that case. A QueuedConnection will remove the need for manual synchronization since the slot will be called in the thread in which the object lives. Qt will handle the synchronization needed to achieve that.

Comment: The sender's object doesn't matter. The comparison between the sending and receiving thread is done at the time the signal is emitted, and is done between the *current* thread (`QThread::currentThread`) and *target* thread (`receiver->thread()`). The *sending object's* thread doesn't figure anywhere in that determination.

Comment: @KubaOber: Indeed you are right. I always assumed that it took the sender objects thread affinity into account and configures the connection statically. But it does indeed check the threads dynamically and will always* do the right thing. Configuring the connection statically as Queued might still be beneficial, since that removes the need for Qt to compare the current/receiver thread. That optimization is obviously only applicable if the signal is always fired from a different thread. That is incidentally exactly the situation of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use [QFuture](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfuture.html) and [QFutureWatcher](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfuturewatcher.html) with QtConcurrent::run().

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible.
just look little example:

in this example we want implement multithread. longProcess function go to thread pool and process in thread pool and after that answer of long process function back to main thread.

**Test.h**

```
Class Test: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void resultAvailable();

    static void doLongProcess(Test *test);

signals:
    void finishedProcess(const QString &massage);

public slots:
    void captureSignal(const QString &message);
};
```

**Test.cpp**

```
void Test::resultAvailable()
{
        QtConcurrent::run(&ContactsModelManager::doLongProcess, this);

        connect(this , &Test::finishedProcess,
                this , &Test::captureSignal);
}

//attention!! doLongProcess is static fnuction
void Test::doLongProcess(Test *test)
{
    //this process is very long
    test->longProcess();
}
 void Test::longProcess()
{
    //do your process

    //at the end emit your signal 
    emit finishedProcess("finished process in another thread");
}

void Test::captureSignal(const QString &message)
{
   Qdebug() << "message is: " << message;
}
```